# Question about eigenvectors of real matrix with real eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two related questions:

Can a real matrix with real eigenvalues have complex eigenvectors?

Is it always the case that a real matrix with real eigenvalues is diagonalisable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If $A$ is real and $\lambda$ is real then the eigenvectors are the solutions to the real linear equation $(\lambda I-A)x=0$ which *can be found* as real.
2. No. For example,
   $$
   \left[\matrix{0 & 1\\0 & 0}\right]
   $$
   has real eigenvalues (both are $0$) and is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Hi, ok for #2, what about when at least when eigenvalue is non-zero?

Comment: @science404: Still no -- this is general for matrices of the form $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{bmatrix}$ when $b\ne 0$. Since $a$ is the only eigenvalue, the only potential diagonalization would be $\operatorname{Diag}(a,a)=aI$. But then we would have $P(aI)P^{-1}=A$ which is impossible because the left-hand side is just $aI$ (as $I$ commutes with $P$).

Answer (score 9):

> Can a real matrix with real eigenvalues have complex eigenvectors?

Of course, if you have an eigenvector with real entries, then you can get one with complex entries simply by multiplying by $i$, for example.

But I think what you really mean to ask is:

> If a real matrix has a real eigenvalue, can it be that *all* eigenvectors for that eigenvalue have complex (that is, non-real) entries?

For that, the answer is "no". If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then the eigenvectors are the solutions to $(A-\lambda I)X=0$. And since $A-\lambda I$ has determinant 0, we can find a real solution by doing plain old Gaussian elimination on it, which involves nothing more dangerous than division by a nonzero number and therefore doesn't take us out of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: indeed, this is the kind of answer i was looking for.  however, i will recognise the solution of A.G. since it is essentially the above.  still, thanks!